# Invoke hidden commands in slave interpreters from master interpreter

Tags: tcl, interpreter

I have create a safe interpreter (`interp create -safe`) and wanted to `source` a file in the slave from the master via `interp invokehidden` command. But I got the following error message at first

```
..
invalid command name "pwd"
    while executing
"pwd"
  (file "C:/MyPkgFile.tcl" line 4)
invoked from within
```

This is because, the file contains the following code at the line number 4

```
set usr_dir [file dirname [file join [pwd] [info script]]]
```

Then with `interp expose`, I gave access to the command `pwd`. Then the error propagated to the `file` command. Again, exposed the command `file` to the slave.  Now, I got

```
not allowed to invoke subcommand dirname of file
    while executing
"file dirname [file join [pwd] [info script]]"
```

How I can give access to sub command  ? I have tried the following,

```
interp expose myslave file
interp expose myslave file dirname
interp expose myslave {file dirname}
```

No luck. :(.  How I can achieve this ?

**I didn't expected myself to exposing these commands to slave, since I am sourcing the file from the master's control via `invokehidden`.  Why this behavior ?**

Comment: FYI, `invokehidden` isn't a transitive permission. It applies to just one command invocation at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose the right command, and to do so in a way that makes it work. This involves getting rather close to one of the nastier misfeatures in Tcl's implementation: the hidden command mechanism doesn't get on well with namespaces due to bugs back in Tcl 8.0 and it's just not been a high priority to fix them since.

You also have to deal with the fact that `rename` won't overwrite commands, and that there's a dummy command already at `::tcl::file::dirname` (which is the one that's giving the “`not allowed to invoke subcommand dirname of file`” error message; indeed, that's all that dummy command does).

```
# Grant the command back into the slave with a temporary name
interp expose myslave tcl:file:dirname DIRNAME
interp eval myslave {
    # Get rid of that dummy command
    rename ::tcl::file::dirname ""
    # Put the exposed command into place
    rename DIRNAME ::tcl::file::dirname
}
```

You're *strongly* advised to do this before letting any unsafe code execute in the interpreter. If you need to run two pieces of unsafe code with only one getting access to the `dirname` subcommand, make two slaves and use aliases to wire them together as necessary.